# AES CBC: Use hash of key as IV when every key is unique?

Tags: aes

I have an app that uses a different random key for every file that is being encrypted.

Am I correct in assuming that this means that I can safely use a hash of the random key as the IV, because that would also lead to a unique IV?

If possible, I would prefer to not store the IV along with the file for performance and storage reasons. OTOH, I obviously don't want to compromise on security...

Thanks for your advice

Comment: I'm curious how you derive your file encryption keys, because it'd be an amazing feat if you can manage these keys and guarantee their uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback so far guys! I can't comment here yet since I don't have any reputation yet (it's my first post here - hello world!), so here's some feedback as an answer: The algorithm does currently indeed works like @Marteen suggested: * get a 32-bit random as the key
* calculate the SHA-256 from it and use half of the data as the IV My assumption: * you can easily and reliably regenerate that IV
* that hash (actually, hash fragment) doesn't give you any pointers about the original key
* While this may introduce some weakness if SHA-256 is broken, it's a very modest risk, especi

Comment: Philip, you appear to have created 2 accounts. Otherwise you would be able to make comments as any question you ask, you should be able to comment on. See [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would be an excellent idea, at least if you use a cryptographically secure hash that has output indistinguishable from random. That's however true for most secure hash algorithms out there. You could - for instance - use SHA-256 and then take the leftmost 128 bits; using the leftmost bits is more or less the industry standard.

You cannot derive the key if the IV gets known because the hash is one way, and an adversary cannot predict the IV because to do that the key should be known. One possible issue is that hash algorithms are not always protected against side channel attacks. Then again, most hash algorithms are not directly susceptible to them either.
Beware that you should document that the resulting IV is static, if you ever start reusing the keys then you'd be in trouble.

---

Alternatively you could use a KDF to derive two values from a master secret, say S. For instance, you could use K = KDF(S, "Key", 128) and IV = KDF(S, "IV", 128) to derive both the encryption key and the IV from one input value.

K | IV = KDF(S, "KeyAndIV", 256) is also often used - it is for instance similar to key derivation in TLS 1.2. This is provably secure and may require less computation time than doing the KDF twice.

The resulting key and IV when using a KDF over a secret value do not depend on each other. This is more secure than having the IV being dependent on the key. A good KDF for key based key derivation (KBKDF) is HKDF.

Comment: Small nitpick: "The resulting key and IV when using a KDF over a secret value do not depend on each other. " this might be slightly misleading in the sense that the two are in fact **not** statistically independent, so they do depend on one another. However with a provably secure KDF we have a proof that ensures us that they are indistinguishable from statistically independent values.

Answer (score 1):

A rule of thumb in cryptography is that it is safest to use a key for one (and only one) purpose.

If you have access to a secure PRNG (psuedo-random number generator), you should use it to generate random and unique IVs every time you encrypt a new message (or file in your case).  This way, the security of your encryption key does not rely on a particular hashing algorithm remaining secure.

If you use AES-CBC to encrypt your files and want to be able to decrypt them, you **must** store the IV.  The decryption algorithm simply will not be able to recover even the first block of data without the IV that was used for encrypting the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the purpose of hashing here is to get a random IV rather than a unique one. The only benefit I can see from your scheme is to save some memory or storage, i.e., no need to store IV for decryption purpose. But hashing can increase the computation work. Since you are using CBC, I assume the file is large enough, then why not store a one-block IV?

IMHO deriving an IV this way may introduce some potential weakness. First, hash functions are not equal to a random oracle. Hashing a secret key may not give you the random IV, at least not provable for now. Second, you can never reuse the key and have to generate a new key for each file. Although this is required in your case, it is not flexible at all.